# What happens if one does not escape the Harvester's mini game?

Tags: warframe

Upon failing to defeat the Harvester mini-boss, you must escape a laboratory. What happens if you fail this escape mission, and do not get all of your stuff back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get anything back and are not allowed to do any other mission until you complete the escape mission.  You can still view the starchart and chat with people, attempting to do another mission will force you to complete the Escape mission first.